# How to resolve getThemedContext() and getSupportFragmentManager()

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I want add Navigation Drawer into my project but when I use this code I have problem with `getThemedContext()` and `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final ListView navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    navList.setAdapter(adapter);
    navList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos,long id){
            drawer.setDrawerListener( new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener(){
                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                    FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    tx.replace(R.id.main, Fragment.instantiate(msgBox.this, fragments[pos]));
                    tx.commit();
                }
            });
            drawer.closeDrawer(navList);
        }
    });
    FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    tx.replace(R.id.main,Fragment.instantiate(msgBox.this, fragments[0]));
    tx.commit();
```

Comment: What the exact problem have you faced with?

Comment: Have you added appropriate imports ? Try calling those methods outside of your anonymous inner class.

Comment: Sorry I forget change class type from `Activity` to `FragmentActivity`